# How to set border width of table in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, html-table, border

I found that some properties can't be used in Wordpress.
The effect below is what I wanted in Wordpress.

[image]

To edit in Text mode in Wordpress.

```
<table border="4" bordercolor="red">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>bash</td>
<td>vim</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I found  that  **border="4" bordercolor="red"** can't work when to publish.
What I get is:

[image]

How to get the desired effect in my Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.table,tr,td
{
  border:solid 4px red !important;
    
  }
```

```html
<table  class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>bash</td>
<td>vim</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```